# how come I can make my system to play 3d video only in landscape mode

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, landscape

I have one app built on react native which offers entertainment contents but I wish to let my users play that 3d video's in landscape mode, how come I can achieve it?

Comment: why not show what you've tried.

Comment: Adding `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` props for `activity` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` will make your app always lanscape.